# Java: why Observer is NOT an interface

Tags: java, interface

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

class Client extends Button implements Observer, ActionListener{
...
}
```

with the code above, when i try to compile it with jdk (v 1.7.0_17) i get the following error:

```
error: interface expected here
class Client extends Button implements Observer, ActionListener{
                                       ^
```

while on other computers it works (I've only checked it on 2 different linuxes) just fine.
I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have an Observer class declared at the same package (or even on the same file)? ... I know it's a long shot, but this is indeed odd.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the classpath. Does it work if you remove `Observer` from the `implements` list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`java.util.Observer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) most definitely *is* an interface.

I suspect you've got an `Observer` class within the same package as `Client`, which would certainly cause that problem.

Complete examples:

This compiles fine:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Client extends Button implements Observer, ActionListener {
    public void update(Observable x, Object y) {}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {}
}
```

This doesn't:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Observer {} // Awooga! Awooga!

class Client extends Button implements Observer, ActionListener {
    public void update(Observable x, Object y) {}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {}
}
```

Comment: @javabeats He beats everyone to it!

Comment: What is "Awooga! Awooga!"? New term? :)

Comment: `//` after an empty class declaration is the new Spring annotation format for implementing requirements without actual code. The declaration `'Awooga! Awooga!'` implements an `Observer<Awooga<Awooga>>`

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: It's the sound of a warning siren. See http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0017424/quotes for example. And the real thing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nv5c-tV8PUo - at about 50 seconds.

Comment: OK, solved.
Indeed I had an Observer class in the file (I made one and then didn't delete the .class file).
Thank you.